# How to wait to render a view in backbone.js till multiple model fetches are completed?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I need to display a graph with multiple line.

I need to fetch 3 signals values from a rest api and wait till I get all of them then I render the graph.

I know how to wait one :

```
this.scores = new ActivityScore();
var that = this;
this.scores.on("change", function(model) {
    console.log(model.attributes);
    that.configuration.series =[{
                    name: 'Activity',
                    data: graphMappers.toGraphSerie(model)}]
            });
this.scores.fetchFromDate("myDate");
```

The new functionality from JQuery $.when is very interesting, I'd try to mix it with backbone.Model, still trying !!

Something like that would be nice :

```
$.when(scores1.fetchFromDate("myDate"),scores2.fetchFromDate("myDate"),graph.render())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been waiting to see if someone come with something cleaner than my approach.

The only solution that comes to my mind is sending a *signal* evey time you finish a `fetch()` and keep the *counting* somewhere, and executing your *waiting code* when the number achieves a concrete number.

To make it more elegant you can use an `Event Aggregator`:

```
// code simplified and no tested
var App = {}
App.NumScores = 3;
App.counter = 0;

App.eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
App.eventAggregator.on( "app:addCounter", App.addCounter );

App.addCounter = function (){
  App.counter ++;
  if( App.counter == App.NumScores ){
    App.eventAggregator.trigger( "app:scoresFetched" );
    App.counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Now it is up to you to call `App.eventAggregator.trigger( "app:addCounter" )` any time you finish one of your `fetch()` you can use the `success` option or anything else. Also you should listen to `App.eventAggregator.on( "app:scoresFetched", <your callback> )` to render your *graph*.

Comment: You could just as well listen for 'sync' on the models